# What's up with planet Aequitas?

Tags: mass-effect-3

I just finished up Priority: Rannoch, and I'm cruising the galaxy for other things that need my particular brand of Shepard-ing.  The Minos Wasteland relay is lit up as if there's a quest there.

In the Fortis system (where the Mass Relay is), the planet Aequitas is highlighted with a green arrow, which is highly unusual.  Trying to investigate yields nothing, and scanning in the system just wakes the Reapers.

What's the point of this planet?

Comment: I had the same problem too, and my personal opinion is that we'll see soon have DLC with some mission there. In ME2 there was an indoctrination device on Aequitas an we had to destroy it... Is that device the cause of the Shepard's indoctrination theory?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apparently it isn't important at all, and [this is a bug many users are reporting](http://social.bioware.com/forum/1/topic/344/index/9708700/1).

Comment: Those forums no longer exist. An example of when it would have been good to quote the source.

Answer (score 1):

Aequitas is a bug, However its also a side N7 Mission from Mass Effect 2 where you investigate reaper disturbances in a mine only to be overrun by husks.. You then detonate the mine to destroy the reaper artifacts and husks.